# VBA .sort letters before numbers / dates

Tags: vba, excel

So im using the .sort method in VBA to sort a range of dates.  Mixed in these dates are occasional letters that mean certain things.

I need a way to sort these letters before the dates, and have not yet found a way to do so with the .Sort method.

Any suggestions?

EX)

```
1/2/16
4/6/16
2/5/16
B
3/25/16
FV
8/10/16
```

--Needs to look like this--

```
B
FV
1/2/16
2/5/16
3/25/16
4/6/16
8/10/16
```

-- Thanks --

--Current Code--

```
Dim x As Workbook
Set x = Workbooks("I G T  Ship Balance sheet Template.xlsx")

lrSort = x.Sheets("Template").Range("A500").End(xlUp).Row

x.Sheets("Template").Range("A2:CJ" & lrSort).Sort Key1:=x.Sheets("Template").Range("G2"), Order1:=xlAscending
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: helper-column which tells (true/false or 0/1 or whatever) for being numeric and then sorting over the helper column first is no option??

Comment: do whatever you are doing to sort, when you are done, select the range of numbers and move them to the bottom of your list, select the whole list and move it back to its original position.

Comment: So I can't really do a helper column because this is being used in a sub  on a full sheet

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume your data are starting from A2. Your results will be placed from B2

Try with below code

```
Sub test()
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim Data() As String
    Dim incre As Long
    Dim Datanumeric() As String
    ReDim Data(lastrow - 1)
    ReDim Datanumeric(lastrow - 1)
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If IsNumeric(Replace(Cells(i, 1), "/", "")) = True Then
            Datanumeric(i - 1) = Cells(i, 1)
        Else
            Data(i - 1) = Cells(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
    Call sort(Data())
    Call sort(Datanumeric())
    incre = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For i = 1 To lastrow - 1
        If Data(i) <> "" Then
            Cells(incre, 2) = Data(i)
            incre = incre + 1
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To lastrow - 1
        If Datanumeric(i) <> "" Then
            Cells(incre, 2) = Datanumeric(i)
            incre = incre + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub sort(list() As String)
    Dim First As Integer, Last As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim temp As String
    First = LBound(list)
    Last = UBound(list)
    For i = First To Last - 1
        For j = i + 1 To Last
            If list(i) >= list(j) Then
                temp = list(j)
                list(j) = list(i)
                list(i) = temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Proof of Work**

[image]

Comment: FYI, his sort range is multiple columns if you didn't notice.  A2:CJ??

Answer (score 0):

EDITED BASED ON NEW INFORMATION:

The below method uses the built-in Excel Custom SortOrder feature to sort based on your requirements. It still uses much of the same helper codes as I previously offered, but this time it uses Excel to perform the sort rather than directly applying from the array. As with the previous code, it does NOT have to be a fixed length list, but you'll have to build in your own logic to test for the size of the sort list. If you need help with that, or anything else, please ask specific questions, and we'll try to offer assistance.

```
Sub TestTheMethod()
    ' Run the SortCustom Method supplying the range in question.
    ' NOTE: Do NOT include the header row.
    ' First arg is the range to sort
    ' Second arg is the key based on which you want to sort (note, the column only matters)

    SortCustom Range("A2:C23"), Range("B1")
End Sub


Sub SortCustom(rInput As Range, rSortField As Range)
    ' First arg is the range to sort WITHOUT headers
    ' Second arg is the sort field (only the column matters)


    Dim nWidth As Long
    Dim nHeight As Long
    Dim vOutput() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    nWidth = rInput.Columns.Count
    nHeight = rInput.Rows.Count

    ReDim vOutput(1 To nHeight, 1 To 1)

    Set rng = Intersect(rInput, rSortField.EntireColumn)
    vOutput = rng

    BubbleSortArrayCustom vOutput, 1

    Set ws = rInput.Parent

    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rng, _
        CustomOrder:=Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vOutput), ",")

    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange rInput
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub BubbleSortArrayCustom(vArray() As Variant, nCompIdx As Integer)
    Dim vPlaceHolder As Variant
    Dim nFirst As Long
    Dim nSecond As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For nFirst = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
        For nSecond = nFirst + 1 To UBound(vArray)
            If CompareTwoValues(vArray(nFirst, nCompIdx), vArray(nSecond, nCompIdx)) Then
                For i = LBound(vArray, 2) To UBound(vArray, 2)
                    vPlaceHolder = vArray(nFirst, i)
                    vArray(nFirst, i) = vArray(nSecond, i)
                    vArray(nSecond, i) = vPlaceHolder
                Next i
            End If
        Next nSecond
    Next nFirst
End Sub

Private Function CompareTwoValues(v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim bOutput As Boolean
    Dim sType1 As String
    Dim sType2 As String

    sType1 = TypeName(v1)
    sType2 = TypeName(v2)

    If sType1 = "String" And sType2 = "String" Then
        bOutput = (v1 > v2)
    ElseIf sType1 = "String" And sType2 <> "String" Then
        bOutput = False
    ElseIf sType2 = "String" And sType1 <> "String" Then
        bOutput = True
    Else
        bOutput = (v1 > v2)
    End If

    CompareTwoValues = bOutput
End Function
```

---

OLD POST:
Take a look at the attached code. I've broken it down into helper functions to hopefully allow you to understand it easier and ultimately modify it to meet your needs.

The code takes a range to sort and the key upon which to sort. Then it uses as array, a custom comparison method, and a bubble sort, to sort the array then replace the original information.

Give it a try on a COPY of your work and see if it meets your needs. Let us know if you need more help with it.

```
Sub TestTheMethod()
    ' Run the SortCustom Method supplying the range in question.
    ' NOTE: Do NOT include the header row.
    ' First arg is the range to sort
    ' Second arg is the key based on which you want to sort (note, the column only matters)

    SortCustom Range("A2:C23"), Range("B1")
End Sub


Sub SortCustom(rInput As Range, rSortField As Range)
    ' First arg is the range to sort WITHOUT headers
    ' Second arg is the sort field (only the column matters)


    Dim nWidth As Long
    Dim nHeight As Long
    Dim vOutput() As Variant

    nWidth = rInput.Columns.Count
    nHeight = rInput.Rows.Count

    ReDim vOutput(1 To nHeight, 1 To nWidth)

    vOutput = rInput

    BubbleSortArrayCustom vOutput, (rSortField.Column - rInput.Range("A1").Column + 1)


    rInput = vOutput
End Sub

Private Sub BubbleSortArrayCustom(vArray() As Variant, nCompIdx As Integer)
    Dim vPlaceHolder As Variant
    Dim nFirst As Long
    Dim nSecond As Long
    Dim i As Long

    For nFirst = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
        For nSecond = nFirst + 1 To UBound(vArray)
            If CompareTwoValues(vArray(nFirst, nCompIdx), vArray(nSecond, nCompIdx)) Then
                For i = LBound(vArray, 2) To UBound(vArray, 2)
                    vPlaceHolder = vArray(nFirst, i)
                    vArray(nFirst, i) = vArray(nSecond, i)
                    vArray(nSecond, i) = vPlaceHolder
                Next i
            End If
        Next nSecond
    Next nFirst
End Sub

Private Function CompareTwoValues(v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim bOutput As Boolean
    Dim sType1 As String
    Dim sType2 As String

    sType1 = TypeName(v1)
    sType2 = TypeName(v2)

    If sType1 = "String" And sType2 = "String" Then
        bOutput = (v1 > v2)
    ElseIf sType1 = "String" And sType2 <> "String" Then
        bOutput = False
    ElseIf sType2 = "String" And sType1 <> "String" Then
        bOutput = True
    Else
        bOutput = (v1 > v2)
    End If

    CompareTwoValues = bOutput
End Function
```

Comment: This would work fine if the list had a defined length and I didnt need to keep all of the formatting / cell highlighting...unfortunately I do

Comment: @JordanAdams The list does't need a defined length, but you'll have to supply the `Range` to the functions based on your own business logic. I've made an edit to my post. Please review it and let us know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you are sorting it now, the numbers appear at the beginning and the letters at the end? If that is always the case (and your letters won't ever start with numbers) couldn't you do the following:

1) Sort everything in decending order, so now your letters appear at the beginning.

2) Then sort just the letters in ascending order, followed by sorting just the numbers in ascending order.

You could identify the letter range after Step 1 by working your way from the top of the sorted list until you came to a number.

Would this achieve what you want?