# Sort with letters before numbers

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting, powerpoint

I am struggling with a bit of code I found on this site. I would like to ensure that strings of letters come before numbers. For example, I have a table and sort by a column with (Page, 1, 3, 6, 10 etc). I would like Page to stay at the top. Currently it works perfectly but puts Page at the end.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am struggling to tune this!

```
Private Sub QuickSortArray(ByRef SortArray As Variant, Optional lngMin As Long = -1, Optional lngMax As Long = -1, Optional lngColumn As Long = 0)
On Error Resume Next

'Sort a 2-Dimensional array

' SampleUsage: sort arrData by the contents of column 3
'
' Call (QuickSortArray arrData, , , 3)

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim varMid As Variant
Dim arrRowTemp As Variant
Dim lngColTemp As Long

If IsEmpty(SortArray) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
If InStr(TypeName(SortArray), "()") < 1 Then  'IsArray() is somewhat broken: Look for brackets in the type name
    Exit Sub
End If
If lngMin = -1 Then
    lngMin = LBound(SortArray, 1)
End If
If lngMax = -1 Then
    lngMax = UBound(SortArray, 1)
End If
If lngMin >= lngMax Then    ' no sorting required
    Exit Sub
End If

i = lngMin
j = lngMax

varMid = Empty
varMid = SortArray((lngMin + lngMax) \ 2, lngColumn)

' We  send 'Empty' and invalid data items to the end of the list:
If IsObject(varMid) Then  ' note that we don't check isObject(SortArray(n)) - varMid *might* pick up a valid default member or property
    i = lngMax
    j = lngMin
ElseIf IsEmpty(varMid) Then
    i = lngMax
    j = lngMin
ElseIf IsNull(varMid) Then
    i = lngMax
    j = lngMin
ElseIf varMid = "" Then
    i = lngMax
    j = lngMin
ElseIf VarType(varMid) = vbError Then
    i = lngMax
    j = lngMin
ElseIf VarType(varMid) > 17 Then
    i = lngMax
    j = lngMin
End If

While i <= j
    While SortArray(i, lngColumn) < varMid And i < lngMax
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    While varMid < SortArray(j, lngColumn) And j > lngMin
        j = j - 1
    Wend

    If i <= j Then
        ' Swap the rows
        ReDim arrRowTemp(LBound(SortArray, 2) To UBound(SortArray, 2))
        For lngColTemp = LBound(SortArray, 2) To UBound(SortArray, 2)
            arrRowTemp(lngColTemp) = SortArray(i, lngColTemp)
            SortArray(i, lngColTemp) = SortArray(j, lngColTemp)
            SortArray(j, lngColTemp) = arrRowTemp(lngColTemp)
        Next lngColTemp
        Erase arrRowTemp

        i = i + 1
        j = j - 1
    End If
Wend

If (lngMin < j) Then Call QuickSortArray(SortArray, lngMin, j, lngColumn)
If (i < lngMax) Then Call QuickSortArray(SortArray, i, lngMax, lngColumn)

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029504/vba-sort-letters-before-numbers-dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ORDER BY 'column\_name' DESC", but numbers before letters requires two statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37102351/order-by-column-name-desc-but-numbers-before-letters-requires-two-statement)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your replies. Unfortunately, these use Excel functions (and SQL in the case of the second comment) which are not available in Powerpoint VBA